# Does data checksumming remain for files with No_COW file attribute on Btrfs filesystem?

Tags: btrfs, checksum

Assume that we don't invoke additional mount options like *nodatacow* and *nodatasum*. Operate only at *file attributes* level, which are controlled with `lsattr`/`chattr`.

1. Does setting **No_COW** on a file ([`chattr +C`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html#ATTRIBUTES)) imply disabling data checksumming on it? The same way as mount options behave ([*nodatacow* implies *nodatasum*](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)#MOUNT_OPTIONS)).
2. May it disable checksumming only for newly written extents and keep for reading existing ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Yes, setting **No_COW** on *empty* file does imply disabling data checksumming of it.

> It's because you can't update the data and the checksum atomically
> -- at some point in the writing process, they must be inconsistent. This is considered a Bad Thing.

Setting **No_COW** on *non-empty* file currently not possible (see #2).

The conclusion is that disabling CoW on a per-file basis also loses checksum correctness of such file. This is not very obvious for a new user of Btrfs, and I think must be added to [Btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

#### 2. No, **No_COW** cannot be set on a *non-empty* file, so `chattr +C` cannot trigger checksumming for extents.

> You can only usefully set +C on a file with no extents.
>
> So by definition there won't be any pre-existing checksummed extents in that file.

---

This answer is a summary based on [Btrfs mailing list discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg57880.html).